# AWS: Ping between multiple namespaces in seperated EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, devops, subnet

I am encountering an issue where I am unable to receive a response when attempting to ping from a namespace located within a public EC2 instance to a private one. To better illustrate my situation, I have included a diagram below.

[image]

Comment: You are not allowing ICMP traffic in your security groups it appears.  Have you tried to enable that?

Comment: Allowing all traffic in security group [Last part of the picture]. Anything else i need to do? @stdunbar

Comment: Sorry, missed that.  You may have better luck at https://serverfault.com/ as this is a pretty detailed networking question.